# Non linear regression using Xgboost

Tags: python, pandas, regression, xgboost, predict

I have a dataframe with 36540 rows. the objective is to predict **y** **HITS_DAY**.

#data

https://github.com/soufMiashs/Predict_Hits

[image]

I am trying to train a non-linear regression model but model doesn't seem to learn much.

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=x,label=y)

xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(learning_rate = 0.1, objectif='reg:linear', max_depth=5,
                          n_estimators = 1000)

xg_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
preds = xg_reg.predict(X_test)
df=pd.DataFrame({'ACTUAL':y_test, 'PREDICTED':preds})
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't tell from the sample data you provided. one possibility is that the learning rate is too high, you can try to reduce it

Comment: @StupidWolf I've reduced the learning rate to 0.001 it gives me almost the same result :/

Comment: can you explain the plot above? Is it a qqplot of your observed values?

Comment: Yes a qqplot of all observed values

Comment: your values are quite skewed. Would it make sense to take the log or do some kind of transformation? your model would reduce the error on the high values. Also it would help if you define what you mean by "not learning much" . This is incredibly vague

Comment: Yes I have already tried to transform the data. The features don't explain target y well. The predicted values are far from the real values. If you have another modeling to better predict y I'm a taker. I point out has many values that equals 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225288/discussion-between-soufianes-and-stupidwolf).

Answer (score 6):

You're not doing anything wrong in particular (except maybe the `objectif` parameter for `xgboost` which doesn't exist), however, you have to consider how `xgboost` works. It will try to create "trees". Trees have splits based on the values of the features. From the plot you show here, it looks like there are very few samples that go above 0. So making a test train split random will likely result in a test set with virtually no samples with a value above 0 (so a horizontal line).

Other than that, it seems you want to fit a linear model on non-linear data. Selecting a different `objective` function is likely to help with this.

Finally, how do you know that your model is not learning anything? I don't see any evaluation metrics to confirm this. Try to think of meaningful evaluation metrics for your model and show them. This will help you determine if your model is "good enough".

To summarize:

1. Fix the imbalance in your dataset (or at least take it into consideration)
2. Select an appropriate objective function
3. Check evaluation metrics that make sense for your model

From this example it looks like your model is indeed learning something, even without parameter tuning (which you should do!).

```py
import pandas
import xgboost

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

# Read the data
df = pandas.read_excel("./data.xlsx")

# Split in X and y
X = df.drop(columns=["HITS_DAY"])
y = df["HITS_DAY"]

# Show the values of the full dataset in a plot
y.sort_values().reset_index()["HITS_DAY"].plot()

# Split in test and train, use stratification to make sure the 2 groups look similar
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42, stratify=[element > 1 for element in y.values]
)

# Show the plots of the test and train set (make sure they look similar!)
y_train.sort_values().reset_index()["HITS_DAY"].plot()
y_test.sort_values().reset_index()["HITS_DAY"].plot()

# Create the regressor
estimator = xgboost.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:squaredlogerror")

# Fit the regressor
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict on the test set
predictions = estimator.predict(X_test)
df = pandas.DataFrame({"ACTUAL": y_test, "PREDICTED": predictions})

# Show the actual vs predicted
df.sort_values("ACTUAL").reset_index()[["ACTUAL", "PREDICTED"]].plot()

# Show some evaluation metrics
print(f"Mean squared error: {mean_squared_error(y_test.values, predictions)}")
print(f"R2 score: {r2_score(y_test.values, predictions)}")
```

Output:

[image: y]

[image: y_train]

[image: y_test]

[image: Actual vs predicted]

```py
Mean squared error: 0.01525351142868279
R2 score: 0.07857787102063485
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you know other SVC, GBM models better adapted to my problem?

Comment: @SoufianeS, other models will be more suitable given the nature of your data. Trees are great, but they can struggle a little with continuous features. SVM or NN is likely to perform better. However, the points about the preprocessing (how to split the data) and the evaluation metrics still apply, regardless of the model type. In general: Just try different models on your data and compare the metrics.

Comment: @SoufianeS, FYI there are a lot of options: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning

Comment: I will then try the other models hoping to have better predictions. Thank you for your time